# How to have 2 insert queries on a single php file

Tags: php, insert

I want to insert data from 2 different tables in a single php file. Only the first insert query will be executed. please help, thank you!

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    include('config.php');
    //$_SESSION['ID'] = $ID

    //Data from guestAdd.php    
    $aID = $_POST['id'];    
    $afrom = $_POST['from'];
    $ato = $_POST['to'];
    $aleaveType = $_POST['leaveType'];

    $selectRemarkSql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT remarkName FROM remarks WHERE remarkID = '$aleaveType';");

    while($row = $selectRemarkSql ->fetch_assoc()) {
        $leaveType = $row["remarkName"];
    }

    $addAbsentSql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO absent(afrom, ato, aleaveType, empID) VALUES('$afrom', '$ato', '$leaveType', '$aID');");
    $leaveLogUpdateSql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO attendance(empID, HoursWorked, remarks, holiday) VALUES('$aID', 00:00:00, '$aleaveType', 'None');")
    header("Refresh: viewAllEmployees.php");

?>
```

Comment: What makes you think that only the first query is executed? Do you even check if there is an error while executing the queries?

Comment: Because when I checked the Database, the inputs are there for the first table, but not on the second. there are no errors too.

Comment: How do you know there are no errors? I don't see you checking the result of `mysqli_query`. All I see is a gigantic security issue with SQL injections.

Comment: because I dont know how sir :( sorry. newbee here

Answer (score 2):

Check for errors between the queries.  Make sure to stop the header refresh so that the error message is displayed.

```
$addAbsentSql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO absent(afrom, ato, aleaveType, empID) VALUES('$afrom', '$ato', '$leaveType', '$aID');");

echo myslqi_error($conn);

$leaveLogUpdateSql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO attendance(empID, HoursWorked, remarks, holiday) VALUES('$aID', 00:00:00, '$aleaveType', 'None');")

//header("Refresh: viewAllEmployees.php");
```